# Printing out all elements of a linked list with given substring

Tags: c, sockets, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a function where with a given substring you can print out all elements that contain it. In theory I thought it would be possible by taking the printAll function and converting it so that instead of printing them all, it should only print the element with the containing substring. But instead I get segmentation fault. What am I missing?

Server

```
void printSub(char sub[101], int *data_socket) {
    struct phonebook *ptr = head;
    
   while(ptr != NULL) 
   {
       if(strstr(sub, ptr->first_name) != NULL || strstr(sub, ptr->last_name) !=  NULL || strstr(sub, ptr->phone_number) != NULL)
      {
      printf("(%s ",ptr->first_name);
      write(data_socket, ptr->first_name, 31);
      printf("%s ",ptr->last_name);
      write(data_socket, ptr->last_name, 31);

      printf("%s) ",ptr->phone_number);
      write(data_socket, ptr->phone_number, 31);

      printf("\n");
      ptr = ptr->next;
       }
    else{
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
   }
}
```

```
// part of if statement where the code executes when user requests a search with given substring
else if(strcmp(data_char_array, "search" == 0)){

                return_value = read(client_info,phone_char_array,101);
                phone_char_array[return_value] = 0;
                write(client_info, "searching", 11);
                printList(phone_char_array, client_info);
            }
```

Client

```
    while(1)
    {
      
        return_value = write(data_socket, send, strlen(send));
        if (return_value == -1) 
        {
            perror("Error occurred while sending! Error at 0x1!");
            exit(-1);
        }

        return_value = write(data_socket, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        if (return_value == -1) 
        {
            perror("Error occurred while sending! Error at 0x2!");
            exit(-1);
        }
      
        return_value = read(data_socket, recieve, 11);
        recieve[return_value] = 0;
        printf("Searching substring: %s\n", recieve);
        if(strcmp(recieve, "searching") == 0)
        {
            return_value = read(data_socket,name,31);
            name[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", name);
            return_value = read(data_socket,last,31);
            last[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", last);
            return_value = read(data_socket,phone,101);
            phone[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", phone);
            printf("Search was successful\n");
```

Comment: Which exact line of code triggers the seg fault? You can immediately get that from running your program in a debugger and is the minimum debugging you should already have done. You can then use the debugger to step thru your code and examine it as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Presuming your network handling is fine, there is nothing wrong with your `printSub()` function for identifying the first, last, phone substrings ***Provided*** that `sub` is a valid *nul-terminated* string. You need to get rid of the `else { ... }` and simply move `ptr = ptr->next;` below it as the `else` is superfluous. I suspect the issue is with not providing a proper *nul-terminated* string, but we can't tell without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The network handling is fine I suppose, since all other functions work as intended. I did check the strings and they all seem to be in order. Im out of ideas

Comment: Note that `else if (strcmp(data_char_array, "search" == 0)) {` has the first close parenthesis misplaced; it should be after the second `"` of `"search"`, not where it is.  That alone would cause a crash — you're passing the value `1` converted to a `char *` to `strcmp()`, and few systems will be happy with that.  Your compiler should also have been complaining about that line.  Heed your compiler!  It knows more about C than you do, especially at this stage of your coding career.